# Split values of one field in values of multiple fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I imported osm data into an index of elasticsearch with gdal and ogr. Now a dataset looks like this:

```
            {
            "_index": "points",
            "_id": "ttZCjIwB1FY7TO4ET-AK",
            "_score": 6.103035,
            "_source": {
                "ogc_fid": 24862,
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        8.7037536,
                        48.8916509
                    ]
                },
                "osm_id": "3330289083",
                "name": "Amt für Umweltschutz",
                "other_tags": "\"addr:city\"=>\"Pforzheim\",\"addr:country\"=>\"DE\",\"addr:housenumber\"=>\"9\",\"addr:postcode\"=>\"75175\",\"addr:street\"=>\"Östliche Karl-Friedrich-Straße\",\"government\"=>\"environment\",\"office\"=>\"government\""
            }
        }
```

Due to the OSM data structure the address data have been imported into the field `other_tags`

to create easier elasticsearch queries, i would prefer an index structure like this:

```
            {
            "_index": "points",
            "_id": "ttZCjIwB1FY7TO4ET-AK",
            "_score": 6.103035,
            "_source": {
                "ogc_fid": 24862,
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        8.7037536,
                        48.8916509
                    ]
                },
                "osm_id": "3330289083",
                "name": "Amt für Umweltschutz",
                "city": "Pforzheim",
                "country": "DE",
                "housenumber": "9",
                "postcode": "75175",
                "street": "Östliche Karl-Friedrich-Straße"
            }
        }
```

i have read that it is possible to mutate data with logstash and there are many examples out there how a mutate filter function could look like. I was searching around for 4 hours, but i couldnt find how to use Logstash with its mutate filter.

Could anyone tell me exactly what the steps are to achieve my goal? Do i need to install something? Do i need to connect to the elasticsearch server and use some commands? Or is that possible by requesting the elasticsearch api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that it is possible to mutate the index structure when reindexing the index, in my case this would be fine, too.

```
POST {{url-elasticsearch}}/_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "points"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "points-wellformed"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang":"painless",
    "source": "if (ctx._source['other_tags'] != null) {def fieldSplit = ctx._source['other_tags'].splitOnToken(','); Map m = new HashMap(); for (item in fieldSplit) { def valueSplit = item.splitOnToken('=>'); if(valueSplit.length == 2) {m.put(valueSplit[0].replace('\"',''), valueSplit[1].replace('\"',''));}} for (entry in m.entrySet()){ctx._source[entry.getKey()] = entry.getValue(); }}"
,  
  }
}
```

I still appreciate solutions which may be faster and more elegant, if someone knows a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing this data using Logstash, you should preferably use the [`kv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) to parse the address data in `other_tags` followed by a `mutate/rename` filter to remove the `addr:` prefix from the field names, like this:

```
filter {
  ...
  kv {
     source => 'other_tags'
     field_split => ','
     value_split_pattern => '=>'
     remove_char_key => '"'
     remove_char_value => '"'
  }
  mutate {
    rename => { 
      "addr:city" => "city" 
      "addr:country" => "country" 
      "addr:housenumber" => "housenumber" 
      "addr:postcode" => "postcode" 
      "addr:street" => "street" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i import this data using gdal: https://gdal.org/index.html

Comment: I suggested logstash because you said `I couldnt found how to use Logstash with its mutate filter.` Can you provide the gdal command you're using?

Comment: i use ```ogr2ogr ES:https://<user>:<password>@<url> <filename>.pbf -append -update points```

Comment: Thanks, I have a solution, I'll post it later today.

Comment: thank you, i am excited about that. currently i am trying to manipulate the data by using the script bock of the ReIndexing API. In my case it is not necessary to keep the data in the same index. Merry Christmas already!